# Conceptual differences between reactjs and dustjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dust.js, serverside-javascript

So I recently started working on a project that requires client side templating for faster response time as well as server side rendering for faster first load as well as SEO optimization.

In this regard, I have been looking at two libraries: [Reactjs](http://facebook.github.io/react/) and [dustjs](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/).

I have used Reactjs previously and am aware of its control flow and virtual dom concepts. I wanted to know how would Dustjs compare with Reactjs viz-a-viz the various concepts:

- Stateful components
- Render
- Two-way data binding
- Server-side rendering
- Feel free to add your own to enrich the answer

Comment: Well, it looks like Dust is just a templating engine while Reactjs is a complete (reactive) rendering framework.

Comment: Added it on programmers.stackexchange.com at https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/246541/conceptual-differences-reactjs-vs-dustjs

Comment: This is not a react vs dust question. I basically want to know the corresponding constructs in dustjs that I have mentioned in reactjs. Also, the control flow. Focussing on specifics here; I have done that by listing out the concepts of Reactjs. Its not a blanket A vs B question.

Comment: React and Dust are not comparable with the concepts you list, because dust doesn’t have any of them (except "render", obviously). And they are also designed to solve different problems.

Comment: Thank you David. That's the answer I was looking for. How do I mark this answered now ?

Comment: @David: It seems to have [can be used for] server-side rendering as well, but you're still right: They're completely different tools.

Comment: @Bergi I was including that in the concept of "Rendering" :)

Comment: to whoever recommended it, **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React and Dust are not comparable with the concepts you list, because dust doesn’t have any of them (except "render", obviously). And they are also designed to solve different problems.